# Rename [c#-10] to [c#-10.0]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Please rename [c#-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-10) to [c#-10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-10.0) as a matter of consistency since every other c# version number tag has `.0` when possible :
[c#-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-2.0), [c#-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-3.0), [c#-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0), [c#-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-5.0), [c#-6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-6.0), [c#-7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-7.0), [c#-8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-8.0) and [c#-9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-9.0)

Comment: I don't see the problem.  They all have 2 significant figures.  (just kidding, this seems like a good idea)

Comment: Would be ideal if someone could do something for its wiki like done for other versions regarding new features/changes etc...

Comment: @JonClements It is still [in preview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10) and I'm not sure how much could/should go into the wiki for the new tag as features may change before the release.